# C++ exit(1) causes IO loss?

Tags: c++, fstream, exit

Here is my program:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream fout("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    for (int isam=0; isam<500; isam++) fout.write((char*) &isam, 4);
    exit(1);
}
```

When I run this on a MacBook, file data.dat is 1 byte long (on AWS, it's 0 bytes), not 2000.  If I increase 500, I eventually get more bytes out, but never the expected amount.  BUT, when I comment out the exit(), everything works as expected regardless of the number of bytes.  It's as if exit() stops buffered output from the previous line of code.  Isn't this a bug? Thanks

Comment: [`exit` is a pretty harsh hammer.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) Read the link and make sure it guarantees all the clean-up you need.

Comment: Hint: It doesn't.

Comment: When is a non-static local object's destructor called?

Comment: You pulled the rug right from under `main` when you called `exit()`.  It isn't a wonder why the results are inconsistent.

Comment: By calling `exit()` as you are, `fout`s destructor is not called - which means no guarantee that its buffers are flushed and the stream is closed.   Either call `fout.close()` before calling `exit()` or remove the `exit()` call - returning from `main()` will cause `fout`s destructor to be called and (once other cleanup is done) `exit()` will be implicitly called anyway.

Comment: Solution: use `return 1;` instead of `exit(1);`.

Comment: Minor point: there are three portable values that can be passed to `exit` (or returned from `main`): `EXIT_FAILURE`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `0`. `0` indicates success, although the value of `EXIT_SUCCESS` is not necessarily 0.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit):

> Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called.

Your `std::ofstream` never gets destructed, then, which means its buffer isn't closed, so anything it still contains (and hasn't been flushed to disk) is therefore lost.

So, no, it's not a bug. It's working exactly as designed.

Comment: It is a bug in the OP's program - based on an incorrect assumption that an object of automatic storage duration will be destroyed when doing `exit()` and/or that the stream will be flushed and closed.

Comment: Well, yes, but I meant it's not a bug in `exit`. It's working exactly as defined.

Comment: Thanks all!  Looks like I need to break the exit(1) habit when debugging.